# How to declare JavaScript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var array1 = [[]];   
m=1;

for(var x=0;x<5;x++){

    for(var y=0;y<5;y++){

        array1[x][y]=m++;

        alert(array1[x][y]);
    }

}
```

Why this alert up to `m=5`  than I generate error??
Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? From what I can tell buy documentation and whatever examples I can find, it should, but I keep getting the error below

Comment: this has nothing to do with php

Comment: What happens when you step through the code line by line with your debugger? That should show you what is happening.

Comment: You can do it like this:

`var array1 = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    array1[x] = [x];
    alert(array1[x]);
}`